# How to pipe output of "drush sql-dump" without warnings

Tags: drush

When I do: `drush sql-dump > somewhere/database.sql` if there will be any warnings printed by Drush, they will be included at the beginning of the created database.sql file. Can we avoid it somehow?

I know there is the `--result-file=` option that ignores all warnings when creating the file, but is there any way to ignore warnings when piping the output? I would like to parse the output before actually saving it into a file if its possible.

`drush 8`

Comment: Which warnings? You could at least avoid that by fixing the underlying issues that trigger these warnings.

Comment: Not always feasible. I would like for my script to work also in foreign environments, which may have their own issues, that are not a priority to fix. There are also cases like this: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3410 where the warning is a drush issue.

Comment: For now I decided to use `| grep -vaE '\[warning\]\s$' >` as a middleman to filter out possible warnings, but it would be great if there would be a better way, as not all possible undesired output will be filtered by this.

Comment: Actually a better filtering device would be `| sed -n '/^--/,$p' >` it makes everything before the first comment in the dump ignored, I think it should do a fine job, but it's a workaround nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `-q` should do the job.

> ```
> $options['quiet'] = array(
>   'short-form' => 'q',
>   'description' => 'Suppress non-error messages.',
> );
> ```

Source: [`function drush_get_global_options`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes%21drush.inc/function/drush_get_global_options/master)

Comment: I tested it. Actually funnily enough, it removes a dump and leaves only warnings in the stdout. :)

Comment: Hahaha, maybe that's what is meant with "quite". OK, but then the warnings get raised by `mysqldump` as you already suggested in the comments to your question. And that seems to be off-topic then I'm afraid.